# Find source of all installed packages on Debian based systems

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

I am trying to find a good method to find the repository for each package that was stored on my system that can be easily parsed.

Backstory:

I have Debian wheezy systems and have setup the wheezy-backports repository, so I could get a newer version of a package.  I made a mistake with my patterns in the pinning configuration, which I didn't notice.  I pinned `*` for the backports repository.  A few weeks later I issued a `apt-get -y dist-upgrade` and wasn't paying attention and upgraded far more packages to the wheezy-backports then I was interested in.

I had backups, so I could easily restore things easily, but this situation made me really want to find a way to find which repository each package came from.

About the closest method I have found so far is like this.  `apt-cache policy $(dpkg -l | awk '/ii/ {print $2}' )`.  Which is somewhat close, but ideally I would like to get a report like this for all the packages.

```
Package<tab>Version<tab>Origin<tab>Suite
```

Where Origin/Suite are the values from the repository Release files.

Comment: Would the `apt-show-versions` package be helpful?

Comment: @FaheemMitha theoretically, that command might be useful, but it seems to be unmaintained.  It doesn't appear to support gzip Package files.  https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=617856

Comment: That';s too bad. I've used it without problems quite recently, specifically without running into this bug. Perhaps submit a patch?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following python script parse the output of `apt-cache policy` and generate the list of all installed packages with the output format

```
Package<tab>Version<tab>Origin<tab>Suite
```

**apt-show-origins**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Should be written with python-apt
# but for now parse the output of apt-cache policy

import os
import re
command    = "apt-cache policy $(dpkg -l | awk '/ii/ {print $2}' )"
stream     = os.popen(command);
content    = stream.readlines()
getOrigin  = False
pkgList    = []

#Parse the output generated by apt-cache
for s in content:
  if(not s.startswith(' ')):
    pkg = type('', (), {})()   #Create an empty object 
    pkg.name = s[:-2]          #Remove trailing ':\n'
  elif(getOrigin):
    pkg.origin = re.split('\s+',s)[2]
    pkg.suite = re.split('\s+',s)[3]
    pkgList.append(pkg)
    getOrigin = False
  elif(s.startswith(' ***')):
    pkg.version = re.split('\s+',s)[2]
    getOrigin = True

#Display the list
for pkg in pkgList:
  print pkg.name    + '\t'\
      + pkg.version + '\t'\
      + pkg.origin  + '\t'\
      + pkg.suite
```

Notes:

- Contrary as what is said in comments `apt-show-versions` is still maintained, check the [official mailing list](https://lists.alioth.debian.org/pipermail/pkg-asv-commits/). But it can't help because it doesn't output the package's origin.

Comment: Personally, if I was writing a Python script from scratch to do this, I'd use the APT Python API, per python-apt.

Comment: Your are right, I said it in the comments of the script but for now it takes less effort and time to do it like this.

Answer (score 1):

Been a while since I posted this question. Anyway, a tool was added a couple years back that also would have solved my underling issue, which was to find extra/outdated/foreign packages installed on the system.

The command `apt-forktracer` is available as a package. When it is run, it will basically show all packages that aren't from the currently installed release.

https://packages.debian.org/stable/apt-forktracer