# How do I measure how stable is my Debian (i.e. number of packages from testing/sid)?

Tags: debian, apt

My Debian spans from legacy abandoned "squeeze" packages to new sid's libs.

I lost track of it a bit and "Which version of Debian do you use" is not a simple question.

How do I measure what percentage of my system is `wheezy`, what is `jessie` and what is unstable?

Comment: `apt-show-versions`, to a first approximation. I'm sure this is a dupe. This one is at least similar - http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/177620/4671

Answer (score 2):

apt-cache can query this information for individual or for all packages.

Here is command line to traverse (not recisely) installed packages and gather statistics:

```
# apt-cache policy '.*' | grep '\*\*\*' -A 1 | grep -v '\*\*\*\|--' | perl -ne 'if(m!dpkg/status!){print "unknown\n"}; if(m!(\d+)\s+\S+\s+(\S+)!){ print "$2\n"}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
   3698 wheezy/main
   2182 unknown
    544 sid/main
    137 jessie/main
     98 wheezy-backports/main
     34 precise/main
     10 wheezy/updates/main
      4 vi/vi
      3 wheezy/contrib
      1 testing/main
```

So, my system looks mostly Wheezy.